# Altering the semantic markup of Drupal pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

So I am reasonably new to Drupal and am having the site behave the way I would like it to. One of the challenges I am facing is that the index.php page (the default, the landing page) when I do open it up, it does not seem to have the semantic markup that I am looking for in a regular HTML page. Understandably Drupal does this internally so it must be hidden somewhere. Pertaining to this stems a few questions which if any of you guys can answer, would be really nice:

1. What is the semantic layout of a default drupal page? I understand it has areas such as sidebars and navigation, body content. Is there a place where I can read how a default Drupal page is organized?
2. How can I alter the semantic layout of a drupal page? Essentially where is it being created, coz that's where I want to go and edit that baby. Also, is this advisable?
3. A very focussed question: I want to change the way the menu looks. I want the menu to acquire the full width of the browser window, unfortunately this is something I cannot do dabbling with the current menus, since they seem to mess around with the sidebars?

Understandably Drupal is great but it does give me a hard time to newcomers. Your answers, criticisms are most welcome!

Thanks

parijat

Answer (score 4):

**Key point: don't view Drupal as a system that can be customized by "simply hacking index.php" or you will be doomed within a matter of days**

Drupal has some architectural concepts that are fundamentally different from many "plain PHP" systems. If you want to use Drupal to do anything beyond the very obvious (install and forget), it is really worth investing your time in understanding how Drupal is structured. This includes (both is not limited to) in understanding how the theming mechanism works, how the menus are generated as well as how the blocks are managed.

The best ever introduction to Drupal concepts for me has been "[Pro Drupal 7 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228385)". It is - by far - the best single resource for learning and understanding Drupal and well worth its price.  Also, in case you already haven't I really urge you to read through the Drupal 7 documentation, especially "[Understanding Drupal](http://drupal.org/documentation/understand)".

Obviously, you can try to simply "reverse-engineer" Drupal, *but - believe me - it is likely much more painful than just understanding the system by reading through a more higher-level documentation.*

Comment: `If you want to use Drupal to do anything beyond the very obvious (install and forget)` made me LOL :D

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to be editing any of the Drupal code files. That way madness lies.

If sounds like you just want to tweak the page templates, though. Some of those will be specified by your theme, so look for a path like `sites/all/themes/omega/omega/templates/` containing a bunch of files such as `html.tpl.php`, which is the `<html> ... </html>` part of our site, for example.

Provided you don't do anything stupid to the `<? php ... ?>` parts of these files, you can edit the semantic HTML to your heart's content.

You will have to delve deeper for some things, though, and different modules will put their HTML in different places.